# To generate javadoc with java 1.7 getting : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in java 1.6 it is successful. Any suggestion?

Tags: java, javadoc

When I am trying to generate javadoc using java 1.7 then I am getting one error due to the exception which is mentioned below, whereas when I am using java 1.6 it is generating javadoc successfully. The metod in which exception is arising is in a jar file.

The error which I am getting in log is as follow :

```
 [javadoc] javadoc: error - In doclet class com.vignette.portal.ant.internal.buildutility.doclet.VignetteDoclet,  method start has thrown an exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 [javadoc] java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.resources.doclets, key doclet.Package
 [javadoc]     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:395)
 [javadoc]     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:355)
 [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.MessageRetriever.getText(MessageRetriever.java:100)
 [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.Configuration.getText(Configuration.java:659)
 [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.markup.HtmlWriter.<init>(HtmlWriter.java:173)
 [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.markup.HtmlDocWriter.<init>(HtmlDocWriter.java:65)
 [javadoc]     at com.vignette.portal.ant.internal.buildutility.doclet.abstraction.HtmlStandardWriter.<init>(HtmlStandardWriter.java:96)
 [javadoc] 1 error
 [javadoc]     at com.vignette.portal.ant.internal.buildutility.doclet.SecondaryPageTypeDoclet$PackageFrame.<init>(SecondaryPageTypeDoclet.java:99)
 [javadoc]     at com.vignette.portal.ant.internal.buildutility.doclet.SecondaryPageTypeDoclet.generate(SecondaryPageTypeDoclet.java:66)
 [javadoc]     at com.vignette.portal.ant.internal.buildutility.doclet.VignetteDoclet.startGeneration(VignetteDoclet.java:74)
 [javadoc]     at com.vignette.portal.ant.internal.buildutility.doclet.abstraction.Standard.start(Standard.java:66)
 [javadoc]     at com.vignette.portal.ant.internal.buildutility.doclet.VignetteDoclet.start(VignetteDoclet.java:46)
 [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [javadoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:280)
 [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:160)
 [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:397)
 [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:167)
 [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
 [javadoc] 7429 warnings
 [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:49)
```

Comment: Looks like the vignette doclet is referrring to an internal resource bundle in the jdk. Looks like those internal resources are not present in the jdk 7 you are using. I'd guess that the vignette code needs to be adjusted to not rely on the internal jdk resources, which are not part of the public api and cannot be relied upon to be present. Have you tried to use a more recent version of vignette?

Comment: @Guenther 
You are right vignette doclet is referrring to following package's
`com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.DocletAbortException;`

`com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.Configuration;`

`com.sun.javadoc.ClassDoc;`

`com.sun.javadoc.RootDoc;`
These internal resources are not accessible in jdk7. Please anyone let me know in jdk7 what are the packages corresponding to these.